# how first level cache works, if we have multiple session objects?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a question regarding 1st level and 2nd level caches.

**2nd level cache**

It is associated with the sessionFactory. Suppose we have two sessions *session1* and *session2* and have one table `student`. We called `get()` from *session1*, then it will hit DB and store the object in *session1* and in the sessionFactory. if we called `get()` from *session2*, then sessionFacory object will copied to session2. If in future we call `get()` it will not hit DB. It will take it from session objects(1st level cache).

Upto this I am clear.

After that another session called *session3* want to update the same record, then if we call `get()` on *session1* and *session2*. what will happen?

**1st level cache**

It is associated with a session. If we have two sessions *session1* and *session2*. We called `get()` from *session1*, it will hit DB and store the object in session1. If we update using *session2*, what will happen if we call `get()` next time from *session1*?

I heard 2nd level cache has some disadvantages. If this is true what are they?

Comment: The session *is* the first level cache. If you call get() on a session and the entity is already cached by this session, the cached value is returned.

Comment: the * key on your keyboard is broken

Comment: Also the shift key doesn't work. And please get in the habbit of asking one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking three questions at once.

**1. Question**

I'm not sure what you mean by

> session3 want to update the same record

Sessions don't have free will. And if they had just from wanting something pretty much nothing happens. But if you use a third session to update the entities already cached in *session1* and *session2* they will keep there cached (now outdated) version. If you use *session1* or *session2* to update the same entity, the update will fail with an optimistic locking exception.

The 2nd level cache will get updated with the new version stored by *session3* though.

**2. Question**

This is the same as the first scenario: *session1* now has a stale object which it will continue to use.

**3. Questions (Drawbacks of the 2nd level cache)**

All kinds of caches have the same challanges:

1. If you put stuff into cache but don't need it again you are wasting CPU time for putting it there and memory for keeping it there.
2. If you look into a cache but don't find what you are looking for you are wasting CPU time for looking there.
3. If you keep stuff in a cache after it changed, you will work with stale data.

Comment: you said." If you use it to update the same entity, the update will fail with an optimistic locking exception.". then how we will eliminate that exception.

Comment: but i am using new session only.i.e session3

Comment: then you don't have that problem.

Comment: in what situations, exceptions will come?

Comment: can you say about cache memorys of hibernate clearly